# SSH key from google colab

Tags: python, git, ssh, google-colaboratory

I want to use `git clone` on `google colab`

First, I tried to git `clone@git.exmaple.com:/~/myGit/myproj.git`

However it shows ssh error (of course)

```
Cloning into 'myproj'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

So one idea, create ssh key every time and put to server's authorized_keys file???

```
!ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:ObNjcAokQn16AMm/ppPq8A4VGUDFKjr3Ck17wrNllMw root@6ef89c7a5cd3
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 2048]----+
|+=B.             |
|.o * .           |
|. * =            |
|.o O o   .       |
|o o E . S        |
|o=.= . + +       |
|+oX.+ . +        |
|.B B.  . .       |
|+o*.             |
+----[SHA256]-----+
```

However I am not sure where ssh key goes and what should I do next.

Also I guess my first idea was wrong.

does anyone help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## ssh key can be found at this folder /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

### Go to github > settings > ssh and gpg_keys

### Add new ssh key

Refer here
https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account

Comment: No problem. Cheers